# While implementing angular material with data source, connect and disconnect, getting error

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am implementing angular material with the data source. After connecting and disconnecting, I'm getting this error:
`Cannot read property 'page' of undefined`

[image]

I've created the project with angular schematics.

Comment: can you please provide your code or stackblitz demo url ?

Comment: I tried using ng generate @angular/material:material-table --name= your-table-name

Comment: Improve readability